# How to replace a small widget for a child when onPressed on a BottomAppBar Icon Item

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `MultiProvider` which have a child of list of Grids as the below code as it was related to the home page like the below code:

```
return MultiProvider(
                                  providers: [
                                    ChangeNotifierProvider(
                                        create: (context) => Properties()),
                                    ChangeNotifierProvider(
                                        create: (context) => Cities()),
                                  ],
                                  child: HomeGrid(_showOnlyFavorites),
                                );
```

and I have also a `bottomNavigationBar` as the below code:

```
bottomNavigationBar: AnimatedContainer(
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
          child: _showBottomBar
              ? BottomAppBar(
                  elevation: 0,
                  shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
                  notchMargin: 10,
                  child: Container(
                    height: 60,
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Row(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            MaterialButton(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                              minWidth: 155,
                              onPressed: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  // currentScreen =
                                  //     Chat(); // if user taps on this dashboard tab will be active
                                  currentTab = 1;
                                });
                              },
                              child: Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Icon(
                                    Icons.home,
                                    color: currentTab == 1
                                        ? Colors.blue
                                        : Colors.grey,
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    'Home',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: currentTab == 1
                                          ? Colors.blue
                                          : Colors.grey,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),

                        // Right Tab bar icons

                        Row(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            MaterialButton(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                              minWidth: 60,
                              onPressed: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  // currentScreen =
                                  //     Settings(); // if user taps on this dashboard tab will be active
                                  currentTab = 3;
                                });
                              },
                              child: Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Icon(
                                    Icons.view_list,
                                    color: currentTab == 3
                                        ? Colors.blue
                                        : Colors.grey,
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    'Property List',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: currentTab == 3
                                          ? Colors.blue
                                          : Colors.grey,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            MaterialButton(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                              minWidth: 77,
                              onPressed: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  // currentScreen =
                                  //     Settings(); // if user taps on this dashboard tab will be active
                                  currentTab = 4;
                                });
                              },
                              child: Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Icon(
                                    Icons.location_searching,
                                    color: currentTab == 4
                                        ? Colors.blue
                                        : Colors.grey,
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    'Map',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: currentTab == 4
                                          ? Colors.blue
                                          : Colors.grey,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              : Container(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                ),
        ),
```

as the below figure is the part of screen which I want to change it:

[image: my_default_screen]

So First I need to set the default provider child related for `Home` `BottomAppBar` Icon as the default child when opening the app and when click the `PropertyList` Icon item just wipe to another child and so on...

So here's the full code for the home Screen:

```
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '../providers/properties.dart';
import '../providers/cities.dart';
import '../widgets/home_grid.dart';
import '../widgets/properties_grid.dart';
import '../app_theme.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  int currentTab = 0;
  ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
  bool _showBottomBar = true;

  _scrollListener() {
    if (_scrollController.position.userScrollDirection ==
        ScrollDirection.reverse) {
      setState(() {
        _showBottomBar = false;
      });
    } else if (_scrollController.position.userScrollDirection ==
        ScrollDirection.forward) {
      setState(() {
        _showBottomBar = true;
      });
    }
  }

  var _showOnlyFavorites = false;
  AnimationController animationController;
  bool multiple = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    animationController = AnimationController(
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 2000), vsync: this);
    _scrollController.addListener(_scrollListener);
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<bool> getData() async {
    await Future<dynamic>.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 0));
    return true;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // final properties = Provider.of<Properties>(context, listen: false);
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 6, // Added
      initialIndex: 0,
      child: Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
        extendBody: true,
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
        floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
        bottomNavigationBar: AnimatedContainer(
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
          child: _showBottomBar
              ? BottomAppBar(
                  elevation: 0,
                  shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
                  notchMargin: 10,
                  child: Container(
                    height: 60,
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Row(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            MaterialButton(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                              minWidth: 155,
                              onPressed: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  // currentScreen =
                                  //     Chat(); // if user taps on this dashboard tab will be active
                                  currentTab = 1;
                                });
                              },
                              child: Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Icon(
                                    Icons.home,
                                    color: currentTab == 1
                                        ? Colors.blue
                                        : Colors.grey,
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    'Home',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: currentTab == 1
                                          ? Colors.blue
                                          : Colors.grey,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),

                        // Right Tab bar icons

                        Row(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            MaterialButton(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                              minWidth: 60,
                              onPressed: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  // currentScreen =
                                  //     Settings(); // if user taps on this dashboard tab will be active
                                  currentTab = 3;
                                });
                              },
                              child: Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Icon(
                                    Icons.view_list,
                                    color: currentTab == 3
                                        ? Colors.blue
                                        : Colors.grey,
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    'Property List',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: currentTab == 3
                                          ? Colors.blue
                                          : Colors.grey,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            MaterialButton(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                              minWidth: 77,
                              onPressed: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  // currentScreen =
                                  //     Settings(); // if user taps on this dashboard tab will be active
                                  currentTab = 4;
                                });
                              },
                              child: Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Icon(
                                    Icons.location_searching,
                                    color: currentTab == 4
                                        ? Colors.blue
                                        : Colors.grey,
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    'Map',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: currentTab == 4
                                          ? Colors.blue
                                          : Colors.grey,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              : Container(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                ),
        ),
        backgroundColor: AppTheme.white,
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            FutureBuilder<bool>(
              future: getData(),
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<bool> snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  return const SizedBox();
                } else {
                  return Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                        top: MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        appBar(),
                        tabBar(),
                        Expanded(
                          child: FutureBuilder<bool>(
                            future: getData(),
                            builder: (BuildContext context,
                                AsyncSnapshot<bool> snapshot) {
                              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                                return const SizedBox();
                              } else {
                                return MultiProvider(
                                  providers: [
                                    ChangeNotifierProvider(
                                        create: (context) => Properties()),
                                    ChangeNotifierProvider(
                                        create: (context) => Cities()),
                                  ],
                                  child: HomeGrid(_showOnlyFavorites),
                                );
                              }
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                }
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget appBar() {
    return SizedBox(
      height: AppBar().preferredSize.height,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, left: 8),
            child: Container(
              width: AppBar().preferredSize.height - 8,
              height: AppBar().preferredSize.height - 8,
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Center(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 4),
                child:
                    Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png', fit: BoxFit.contain),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, right: 8),
            child: Container(
              width: AppBar().preferredSize.height - 8,
              height: AppBar().preferredSize.height - 8,
              color: Colors.white,
              child: Material(
                color: Colors.transparent,
                child: InkWell(
                  borderRadius:
                      BorderRadius.circular(AppBar().preferredSize.height),
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.location_on,
                    color: AppTheme.dark_grey,
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      multiple = !multiple;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget tabBar() {
    return SizedBox(
      height: AppBar().preferredSize.height,
      child: TabBar(
        isScrollable: true,
        unselectedLabelColor: Colors.green,
        labelColor: Colors.blue,
        indicatorColor: Colors.blue,
        labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
        tabs: [
          Tab(
            child: Text('All'),
          ),
          Tab(
            child: Text('Office'),
          ),
          Tab(
            child: Text('Commercial'),
          ),
          Tab(
            child: Text('Land'),
          ),
          Tab(
            child: Text('House/Villa'),
          ),
          Tab(
            child: Text('Apartement'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and this is the `PropertiesList` child I want to be swiped when on pressed as it was related for a Grid:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import './popular_property_item.dart';

import '../providers/properties.dart';

// import '../providers/properties.dart';

class PropertiesGrid extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool showFavs;

  PropertiesGrid(this.showFavs);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final propertiesData = Provider.of<Properties>(context);
    // final productData = Provider.of<Cities>(context);
    final properties =
        showFavs ? propertiesData.favoriteItems : propertiesData.items;
    return SizedBox(
      height: 250,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: GridView.builder(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              itemCount: properties.length,
              itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
                // builder: (c) => products[i],
                value: properties[i],
                child: PopularPropertyItem(
                    // products[i].id,
                    // products[i].title,
                    // products[i].imageUrl,
                    ),
              ),
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 1,
                childAspectRatio: 3 / 4,
                crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                mainAxisSpacing: 10,
              ),
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

So how can I navigate through child when on press on `bottomAppBar` Icon....

I hope this would be clear enough.. :)

Comment: you can use a `PageView` and sync it with `bottomNavigationBar` as shown in this [article](https://medium.com/@KarthikPonnam/flutter-pageview-withbottomnavigationbar-fb4c87580f6a).

Comment: @hiwajalal thanks alot for your comment could you give me a small brief related to example... I appretiate your efforts :D

Comment: sure, but what exactly you need help with? you should just provide the `PageView` as body of your scaffold, and then sync it with `bottomNavigationBar`.

Comment: @hiwajalal here's the problem that the body contains another app bar and an Expanded widget with a grid view... as I need to change the expanded widget only  and kust keep the top and bottom tab bar as I shows in the post I hope you have got me... I need only to change a small part in body not the whole body :D

Comment: then just make that part a `PageView`!

Comment: @hiwajalal yeah I got you, I'll read this article then and have a try thanks a lot for your support :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215454/discussion-between-hiwa-jalal-and-mahmoud-harooney).

Comment: Short and clear questions get the best answers. I think this question should be improved.