# How to create a page view for an external class

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create a page view for an external classes as to swipe between pages while pressing `bottomNavigationBar` Icon Item as related to the below question:

[How to replace a small widget for a child when onPressed on a BottomAppBar Icon Item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62241805/how-to-replace-a-small-widget-for-a-child-when-onpressed-on-a-bottomappbar-icon)?

So I am trying to follow the below article as to apply this the paging when click the Icon related for `bottomNavigationBar`...

https://medium.com/@KarthikPonnam/flutter-pageview-withbottomnavigationbar-fb4c87580f6a

When I am trying to add this part to my code:

```
Widget buildPageView() {
    return PageView(
      controller: pageController,
      onPageChanged: (index) {
        pageChanged(index);
      },
      children: <Widget>[
        HomeGrid(),
        PropertiesGrid(),
        // Yellow(),
      ],
    );
  }
```

I found a syntax error as the below one for the `HomeGrid()` and `PropertiesGrid()`:

```
1 positional argument(s) expected, but 0 found.
Try adding the missing arguments.dartnot_enough_positional_arguments)
```

I need some one help me to solve this issue for how to perform the way of this article and apply it to my code...

How can I swipe between a small part of screen based on a `Grid` widgets....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error you are getting is because of how you created your widget, as they require a parameter to be passed to them, to make the parameter named and optional use { } with your parameters to make them positional optional use [ ] with your parameters, and as for changing a part of screen you can use the `PageView` widget as in the article but now you should add a `Stack` like the example below, i took some code from the article and just tweaked it a little, i also provided you with many comments on code so it make it easier for you to understand:

```
class CustomPages extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CustomPagesState createState() => _CustomPagesState();
}

class _CustomPagesState extends State<CustomPages> {
  // this is used to control the page being displayed in PageView
  PageController pageController = PageController(
    initialPage: 0,
    keepPage: true,
  );

  // this is used to change the displayed page
  void pageChanged(int index) {
    setState(() {
      bottomSelectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  // this build a PageView widget
  Widget buildPageView() {
    return PageView(
      controller: pageController,
      onPageChanged: (index) {
        pageChanged(index);
      },
      children: <Widget>[
        FlutterLogo(),
        FlutterLogo(colors: Colors.red),
        FlutterLogo(colors: Colors.yellow),
      ],
    );
  }

  // this is the index of bottomNavigationBar
  int bottomSelectedIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
              child: Text('This won\'t change', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30)),
            ),
            buildPageView(),
          ],
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          currentIndex: bottomSelectedIndex,
          items: buildBottomNavBarItems(),
          onTap: (index) => bottomTapped(index),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  // this build item for bottomNavigationBar
  List<BottomNavigationBarItem> buildBottomNavBarItems() {
    return [
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: new Icon(Icons.home), title: new Text('1')),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: new Icon(Icons.search),
        title: new Text('2'),
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.info_outline), title: Text('3'))
    ];
  }

  // this get called when bottomNavigationBar item is called and change the 
  // index of item and page in the PageView
  void bottomTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      bottomSelectedIndex = index;
      pageController.animateToPage(index, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500), curve: Curves.ease);
    });
  }


}
```

[image: as you can see the Text doesn't change only the Flutter logo does]